# sum and count D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to  get a count of the number of sites and the sum of the sites from in D3, below is my data structure, this represents a unidirectional network flow The json below consists of 2 objects nodes and links

```
var data = {
    "nodes": [
        {
            "id": "s1",
            "val": 12
        },
        {
            "id": "s2",
            "val": 12
        },
        {
            "id": "s3",
            "val": 12
        },
        {
            "id": "s4",
            "val": 12
        },
        {
            "id": "s5",
            "val": 12
        },
        {
            "id": "s6",
            "val": 12
        }
    ],
    "Links": [
        {
            "n1": "s1",
            "n2": "s2",
            "amount": 10
        },
        {
            "n1": "s2",
            "n2": "s3",
            "amount": 10
        },
        {
            "n1": "s2",
            "n2": "s4",
            "amount": 10
        },
        {
            "n1": "s2",
            "n2": "s6",
            "amount": 10
        },
        {
            "n1": "s3",
            "n2": "s1",
            "amount": 10
        },
        {
            "n1": "s4",
            "n2": "s5",
            "amount": 10
        },
        {
            "n1": "s5",
            "n2": "s6",
            "amount": 10
        }
    ]
};
```

The site can be at either n1 or n2, it dosent matter, I need to format it in to the following structure (this is the correct output)

```
[
    {
        "n": "s1",
        "num": 2,
        "sum": 20
    },
    {
        "n": "s2",
        "num": 4,
        "sum": 40
    },
    {
        "n": "s3",
        "num": 2,
        "sum": 20
    },
    {
        "n": "s4",
        "num": 2,
        "sum": 20
    },
    {
        "n": "s5",
        "num": 2,
        "sum": 20
    },
    {
        "n": "s6",
        "num": 2,
        "sum": 20
    }
]
```

I have tried using the following code, this is not working at all

```
var sums = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.n1; })
  .rollup(function(v) { return {
    num: v.length,
    sum: d3.sum(v, function(d) { return d.amount; })
  .entries(data.links);
```

Comment: what are the rules for summing it ?

Comment: @Kunal Mukherjee the sum is coming from links.amount. however s1 can be at n1:s1 or n2:s1, all amounts should be summed {n1:s1, n2:s2, amount : 10},{n1:s3, n2:s1, amount : 10 } . the s1 sum is 20 and count is 2, s2 sum is 10 and count is 1 etc